# Trying to use VBA to scan sheet, find cells containing a specific word, and shift only those cells up a row

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I'm putting a macro together that formats a spreadsheet pulled from a database.  Any time it's generated, I have to move the "Sum" lines up one cell.  I'm looking for some tips on how to set up the macro to scan the spreadsheet for the word "Sum" and shift only the cells containing it up one cell.  Anything I've tried has either not worked at all or shifted the entire column up.

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("I2:I500")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value <> "Sum" Then
    cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value = cel.Value
    End If
Next cel
```

This is the closest I've come to getting it to work.  The problem is that it shifts everything in that column up one cell.  I only need the cells containing "Sum" to move.

Comment: Use `If cel.Value Like "*Sum*" Then`

Answer (score 0):

- It is assumed that Sum always appears as the leftmost three characters in the target cell.

Please try.

```
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Set SrchRng = Range("I2:I500")
    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If UCase(Left(cel.Value, 3)) = "SUM" And cel.Row > 1 Then
            cel.Offset(-1, 0).Value = cel.Value
            cel.Value = ""
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm